# Read stdin to run a script on certain keystroke without interfering in programs/games

Tags: linux, bash, debian

My goal is to run a script every time I push the <kbd>R</kbd> key on my keyboard:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -50 .local/share/binding\ of\ isaac\ afterbirth+/log.txt | grep "on seed" | awk '{print $(NF-1) $NF}' > /home/fawk/seed
```

I already tried to do this with a program called xbindkeys but it would interfere and pause the game.

Then I tried it with another bash script using the `read` command to execute the first script but my knowledge isn't that great so far. Reading and experimenting for hours didn't lead anywhere.

The purpose is to feed a game-seed to OBS. The easiest way seems to create a (text-)file containing the seed for OBS to pick up. All I want is that seed (1st script) to be written into a file.

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
read -r 1 k <&1
if [[ $k = r ]] ; then
exec /home/fawk/seedobs.sh
fi
done
```

and many other variations but didn't get closer to a solution.

Comment: If you're playing a game the terminal window where the script is running won't have focus and won't receive keystrokes. I don't think scripting is going to give you the answer. This question is more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's doable if one parses evdev events, but that's much easier to do in a language like Python (which has tools for understanding binary structures, and also a ready-to-use evdev library available). Bash is really the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Now, is there a command line tool you can run to generate a textual description of those events? If memory serves, yes. Could you use bash to parse those textual descriptions? Yes. Is it a good choice of tools for that job? Still no; bash reads data character-by character; if there's a bunch of mouse or joystick data in the feed I could conceive of it falling behind and having significant latency before it got to your keypress.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I clearly underestimated the effort it takes to come to a solution. I'll read into your suggestions since Python like evdev events aren't new to me.